# Given a positive real number $a$, the function $f(x)=(e^{x}-ax)(x-a\ln x)$ has exactly three distinct real zeros. What is the value of $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Given a positive real number $a$, the function $$f(x)=(e^{x}-ax)(x-a\ln x)$$ has exactly three distinct real zeros. What is the value of $a$? I only know that the approximate value of $a$ is $3.21$.Can I get a closed-form solution to $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a>e$ both $e^x-ax$ and $x-a\log x$ have two zeros. For $f(x)$ to have exactly three zeros you'll need that one zero of $e^x-ax$ to coincide with one of $x-a\log x$. That means that you need to solve the system of equations $$e^x-ax=0$$ $$x-a\log x=0$$

Eliminating $x$ from this equations gives the following for $a$:
$$a^{1/(a-1)}=\frac{a}{a-1}\log a$$ which I doubt has a closed solution but can be numerically approximated to get $a\approx 3.2128347673366522288$

Comment: Thank you！I get it！

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to work in terms of $x$ and search for the intersection of the two functions
$$f(x)=\frac {e^x}x \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x)=\frac x{\log(x)}$$ or for the unique real zero of function
$$h(x)=e^x\, \log(x)-x^2$$

By inspection, the solution is smaller than $2$. Use this value as $x_0$ for Newton-like methods of order $n$ and perform **a single** iteration to have an explicit value (for an *approximation*.

For example, without possible simplifications,
$$x_1^{(2)}=\frac{2 \left(-4+e^2+e^2 \log (2)\right)}{-8+e^2+2 e^2 \log (2)}$$
$$x_1^{(3)}=\frac{2 \left(32-12 e^2+2 e^4-8 e^2 \log (2)+3 e^4 \log
   (2)\right)}{96-20 e^2+2 e^4+4 e^4 \log ^2(2)-40 e^2 \log (2)+5 e^4   \log (2)}$$

Continuing but converting the expression to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_1^{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 & 1.7670994 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & 1.7053859 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 & 1.6954467 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 & 1.6945564 & \text{no name} \\
 6 & 1.6945722 &  \text{no name} \\
 7 & 1.6945952 &  \text{no name} \\
 8 & 1.6946002 & \text{no name} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

the "exact" solution being $x=1.6946009$, surprizingly close to $(1+\log(2))$

$$a\sim f\left(1+\log(2)\right)\qquad\implies \qquad a\sim \frac{2 e}{1+\log (2)} =3.21092$$

Comment: This answer is detailed.Thank you very much！